# Cannot create layout resource file

Tags: android

[image]
Error which I face the application is run perfectly. but why the red line is ?? 
I want to remove it.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Two options

1. Build > Rebuild Project
2. or Click on `File > Invalidate Caches / Restart`